# How to share IPSec VPN connection to eth1 or wlan0?

Tags: vpn, sharing, ipsec

I have an Ubuntu pc with a working connection to my VPN server via Strongswan. The connection is IKEv2 with EAP MSCHAPv2 auth.  On my Ubuntu pc I have second Ethernet port. I want to share my VPN connection to other devices via second Ethernet port. What configuration do I need to share IKEv2 VPN over second Ethernet port?

Comment: status please...

Comment: as soon as my vpn connection goes live, second ports doesn't provide IP addresses. so it's not working. it works fine without vpn.

Comment: from reading around I understand that I need to use "--match policy --pol ipsec", but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Did you install dnsmasq-base?

Comment: yes, I did. actually it was already installed.